# Issue Linq in entity framework?

Tags: linq, formula

Could anyone optimize this linq in entity:

```
<code>
var query = from s in context.Spots
            where (s.Lat - s.Long) <= radius
            orderby (s.Lat - s.Long) ascending
            select new { SpotId = s.SpotId, Distance = (s.Lat - s.Long)};
</code>
```

I want to optimize math formula (s.Lat - s.Long). I don't want to use it three times!

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [let clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx):

```
var query = from s in context.Spots
        let dist = (s.Lat - s.Long)
        where dist <= radius
        orderby dist ascending
        select new { SpotId = s.SpotId, Distance = dist};
```